# Too many method within method?

Tags: c#, function, methods

In my `Main()` I call `MethodA()` from `ClassA`, which will then call `MethodB()` from `ClassB`, and so on and so forth. This goes for about 5 layers before it finally returns the value I want back to `Main()`.

There is an object that is being passed round and processed in each methods.

Is this a good practice? Is there another approach for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a good practice.

And 5 levels is still very close to nothing. At 500 you might pause to think about it, at 5000 it gets worrisome.

> There is an object that is being passed round and processed in each methods.

It will be passed by reference, so no overhead there.

Comment: I agree that that's how OOP actually does work. However, 5000? Isn't it much? For me, having 5000 methods in call stack sounds like a debugging hell.

Comment: Indeed, 500 seems worrisome to me already. Okay, you can have some recursion, but a depth of 500, is that really necessary? I think you have to take a look at your design already then.

Comment: 500-5000 sounds more like a recursion. And with 5000+ recursions you will have to think about memory usage above all other things.....as that COULD get a bit towards the limits there.

Comment: The 5000 is a little exaggeration. Just to emphasize that 5 is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A depth of 5 for a call stack is nothing. Before you have anything done in a Windows Forms or WPF application, you have a call stack of 5 already.

Putting a frame on the stack does cost something, but you don't have to worry too much about that for now. You have to look out if you are going to do things recursive, since the amount of frames can increase rapidly. This can get expensive.

You have to worry if you lose overview of the call stack. In my opinion a call stack of 100 gets hard to read, for sure if you are a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an algorithm to - for example - recursively run through an array of chars to produce every combination of characters (no, I'm not a brute-force password hacker!) - then a deep recursive call stack maybe part of the solution.

As Henk Holterman says, each object passed by reference is just a pointer, 32-bit integer or 64-bit integer depending on processor architecture / build config.  That's 4 bytes or 8 bytes each call.